# Why is "Ubuntu and Canonical are registered trademarks of Canonical Ltd." not mentioned in Ask Ubuntu Meta?

Tags: support, status-completed, design

In the bottom of [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) website, we can notice this:

[image: Screenshot of the bottom of https://askubuntu.com/]

> Ubuntu and Canonical are registered trademarks of Canonical Ltd.

But in Ask Ubuntu Meta, the aforementioned text is not there.

[image: Screenshot of the bottom of https://meta.askubuntu.com/]

Why is the text there in Ask Ubuntu but not in Ask Ubuntu Meta?

We do use the Ubuntu logo in Ask Ubuntu Meta, so I think it would be appropriate if the aforementioned text is also mentioned in Ask Ubuntu Meta.

Comment: Just a guess, but it may be that all the meta sites use the same template and are not customizable like the main sites are. But it should probably be added though since the Ubuntu logo is being used as you mentioned.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[JNat](https://meta.askubuntu.com/users/306823/jnat), Community Manager for Stack Exchange, [has added the tag](https://meta.askubuntu.com/posts/19699/timeline#history_0a81b83c-757e-4315-a935-2e5bc26bdddc) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

Now, "Ubuntu and Canonical are registered trademarks of Canonical Ltd." is also mentioned in Ask Ubuntu Meta.

Current screenshot of the bottom of Ask Ubuntu Meta:

[image: Screenshot of the bottom of Ask Ubuntu Meta]